# Looking at TcpClient.Client properties closes the Socket in vs debug

Tags: c#, debugging, tcpclient, disconnect

I found something strange
I opened a TcpClient and debuged it
And when i wached the TcpClient.Client properties it closed the socket(the Connected property was false)

Why?

I am using c# in vs2010

Comment: does it also happens on other machines aside from yours?

Comment: Yes - but the computer type is the same

Comment: there are many possible causes for that like a port conflict, firewall, or a bug in your code... could you provide some more details so we can help you

Comment: If i dont look at its properties its stays open

Comment: The code is only opening a connection and then in debug mode looking at the properties. To connect I used the BeginConnect metond

Comment: also happens for me, using VS2008 and C++/CLI. simple program for testing:  TcpClient^ tcpclient = gcnew TcpClient;
IPAddress^ ipaddress;
bool bSuccess = Net::IPAddress::TryParse("127.0.0.1", ipaddress);
tcpclient->Connect(ipaddress, 50000);